# Jquery - Signs (for alias) that don't disturb the js Code

Tags: jquery, alias

As we know, jQuery uses $ as an alias for the jQuery.
Are there others signs available that i can use for my own Javascript-Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that an "alias" is just another variable. Aside from the underscore and dollar characters, from the [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6):

> Unicode escape sequences are also permitted in an IdentifierName,
>   where they contribute a single character to the IdentifierName, as
>   computed by the CV of the UnicodeEscapeSequence (see 7.8.4). The \
>   preceding the UnicodeEscapeSequence does not contribute a character to
>   the IdentifierName. A UnicodeEscapeSequence cannot be used to put a
>   character into an IdentifierName that would otherwise be illegal. In
>   other words, if a \ UnicodeEscapeSequence sequence were replaced by
>   its UnicodeEscapeSequence's CV, the result must still be a valid
>   IdentifierName that has the exact same sequence of characters as the
>   original IdentifierName. All interpretations of identifiers within
>   this specification are based upon their actual characters regardless
>   of whether or not an escape sequence was used to contribute any
>   particular characters.

To put it simply, valid JavaScript variable identifiers have to start with a letter, dollar symbol or underscore symbol, and can contain unicode character escape sequences. The relevant part of the grammar from the spec:

> ```
> IdentifierStart ::
>     UnicodeLetter
>     $
>     _ 
>     \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
> ```

In the case of writing a library, if you want to use `$` there shouldn't be a problem - jQuery provides it's `noConflict` method to handle that exact situation.

Comment: I prefer to name my libraries ᾫ (U+1FAB: GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA WITH DASIA AND VARIA AND PROSGEGRAMMENI), not to be confused with ᾨ, ᾩ, ᾪ, ᾬ, ᾭ, ᾮ, or ᾯ.